# Is my Android applicationId the reason why react-native-auth0 universal login flow is not working?

Tags: android, react-native, auth0

Long story short, I can’t figure out why the react-native-auth0 universal login flow is not working on Android, while it works just fine on iOS.

The issue for me is the following - I open the login flow through authorize(), and once I input my email and password, I get a successful login log, however, I don’t get redirected back to my app and I just stay on the email and password screen.

In order to figure out what was happening, I created a fresh React Native application with an applicationId of com.awesomeproject . Using that applicationId, the login flow worked just fine. I then changed the applicationId to com.awesomeProject and the same problem occurred that happens in my own application.

My own application has the following applicationId - com.project.projectApp and obviously the first thing that came to my mind was to rename the package name to com.project.projectapp. I was fully expecting this to work, but it didn’t and the error persisted, even though this worked in the fresh React Native application.

Could com.project.projectApp or com.project.projectapp still be invalid applicationIds?

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your problem I think you should match the applicationId with Allowed callback URLs in Auth0. You can find your applicationId under project>android>app>build.gradle

The allowed callback URL should looks like this for android.

```
PACKAGE_NAME.auth0://{TENENT_NAME}.auth0.com/android/PACKAGE_NAME/callback
```